# F# WPF script, draw graphics on button click

Tags: wpf, winforms, f#, drawing

I am tinkering with using F# scripts and I'm just wanting to draw lines on a blank Windows Form with a simple button click. Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do here:

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let form = new Form(Width = 400, Height = 400, Text = "draw test")
let panel = new FlowLayoutPanel()
form.Controls.Add(panel)

let paint(e : PaintEventArgs) =
    let pen = new Pen(Color.Black);  
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new PointF(100.0f, 100.0f), new PointF(200.0f, 200.0f))

let button = new Button()
button.Text <- "Click to draw"
button.AutoSize <- true

button.Click.Add(fun _ -> form.Paint.Add(paint)) // <- does not draw a line on click

panel.Controls.Add(button)

//form.Paint.Add(paint) <- here, if uncommented, it will draw a line when the script is run
form.Show()
```

If I take the `form.Paint.Add(paint)` uncomment it above `form.Show()`, then of course it will draw on the form, but I'm trying to do it with a button click. It's not exactly clear to me how to make this happen in a script like this, and I've been scouring all over for a similar example in F#. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 2 suggestions: 1) stick with either WinForms or WPF, and reflect that I'm the question (tags), and 2) I don't think button.Click.Add() is doing what you think. You should be about to use about the same syntax as C#, since the framework is built in an object oriented style

Comment: Have you seen this? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/events

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks!

Comment: your code for Winforms not WPF. Although, I'd use WPF ;)

Comment: Does `form` variable still exist, when you click? I suppose this variable is not captured?

Comment: I suggest you write an answer about WPF instead of making edit in question

Comment: I assumed Winforms is what the author meant (based on his code); I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add your Paint event handler before the form is drawn for the first time, then it will draw using that handler.

If you add it after, you need to make sure the form then redraws itself. You could for instance call `Refresh` or `Invalidate` on it.
Ex.:

```
button.Click.Add(fun _ -> form.Paint.Add(paint); form.Invalidate())
```

Comment: This is good for Winforms. I've added something I've slapped together for WPF above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Originally an edit, I moved it to the answer section:

Okay, so I was confused about the difference between WPF and Winforms due to the fact that I have seen the terms used together various places... @Asik has added an answer for Winforms, but here I have slapped together a working .fsx script specifically for WPF based on several [FSharp Snippets](http://fssnip.net/) (as well as several Google searches) which can also be compiled if so desired. I'll update this as needed or requested. Also, just to point out, the whole motivation behind this is to be able to quickly test drawing graphics via FSI.

```
#r @"PresentationCore"
#r @"PresentationFramework"
#r @"WindowsBase"
#r @"System.Xaml"
#r @"UIAutomationTypes"

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Media
open System.Windows.Shapes
open System.Windows.Controls

let window = Window(Height = 400.0, Width = 400.0)
window.Title <- "Draw test"
let stackPanel = StackPanel()
window.Content <- stackPanel
stackPanel.Orientation <- Orientation.Vertical

let button1 = Button()
button1.Content <- "Click me to draw a blue ellipse"
stackPanel.Children.Add button1

let button2 = Button()
button2.Content <- "Click me to draw a red ellipse"
stackPanel.Children.Add button2

let clearButton = Button()
clearButton.Content <- "Click me to clear the canvas"
stackPanel.Children.Add clearButton

let canvas = Canvas()
canvas.Width <- window.Width
canvas.Height <- window.Height
stackPanel.Children.Add canvas

let buildEllipse height width fill stroke =
    let ellipse = Ellipse()
    ellipse.Height  <- height
    ellipse.Width   <- width
    ellipse.Fill    <- fill
    ellipse.Stroke  <- stroke
    ellipse

let ellipse1 = buildEllipse 100.0 200.0 Brushes.Aqua Brushes.Black
Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse1, canvas.Width / 10.0) //messy, will fix at some point!
Canvas.SetTop(ellipse1, canvas.Height / 10.0)
let ellipse2 = buildEllipse 200.0 100.0 Brushes.Red Brushes.DarkViolet
Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse2, canvas.Width / 4.0)
Canvas.SetTop(ellipse2, canvas.Height / 5.0)

let addEllipseToCanvas (canvas:Canvas) (ellipse:Ellipse) =
    match canvas.Children with
    | c when c.Contains ellipse ->
        canvas.Children.Remove ellipse
        canvas.Children.Add(ellipse) |> ignore //needs to be removed and readded or the canvas complains
    | _ ->
        canvas.Children.Add(ellipse) |> ignore

button1.Click.Add(fun _ -> addEllipseToCanvas canvas ellipse1)
button2.Click.Add(fun _ -> addEllipseToCanvas canvas ellipse2)
clearButton.Click.Add(fun _ -> canvas.Children.Clear())

#if INTERACTIVE
window.Show()
#else
[<EntryPoint; STAThread>]
let main argv =
    let app = new Application()
    app.Run(window)
#endif
```